# How to fix Null-Pointer exeption by RapidClipse auto generated code

Tags: java, vaadin, rapidclipse

With RapidClipse I build a page with three elements. 
A drop-down field, a XdevTable and a XDevfieldGroup.
The drop-down field is filled by database table content (works fine)
The table should be filled after selecting a value out of drop-down field (works fine)
 
After selecting a value out of the XDevTable the related row should be editable by the fieldgroup.

After selecting  a row in the table I get a null-pointer exeption:

```java
Mai 27, 2019 4:41:19 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
    SCHWERWIEGEND: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at
com.xdev.ui.entitycomponent.table.AbstractBeanTable.getSelectedItem(AbstractBeanTable.java:180)
at com.xdev.ui.masterdetail.FieldGroupMasterDetailConnection.lambda$0(FieldGroupMasterDetailConnection.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1015)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.fireValueChange(AbstractField.java:1161)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:571)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.setValue(AbstractSelect.java:735)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:468)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.changeVariables(AbstractSelect.java:547)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.changeVariables(Table.java:2933)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:616)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:463)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:406)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1435)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
at com.xdev.communication.XdevServlet.service(XdevServlet.java:212)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I am right, I assume, that there is a leak identifying the item which is selected in the table. 
But I still did what/how is described in RapidClipse Training. 
So the connection between table and fieldgroup is done by the property "ConnectedForm" inside the table.

The connection from drop-down field to table is done by following code:

```
private void comboBox_valueChange(final Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {

    try {

        Integer varMainClass = 0;
        varMainClass = this.comboBox.getSelectedItem().getBean().getId();

        Notification.show("Kuck a mole: ", this.comboBox.getSelectedItem().getBean().getGroupName()
                , Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        final BeanItemContainer<TGroup> mySubClasses = new BeanItemContainer<>(TGroup.class);
        mySubClasses.addAll(new TGroupDAO().getAllSubClassByMainClassId(varMainClass));
        this.table.setContainerDataSource(mySubClasses);
        this.table.setVisibleColumns("id", "groupName");
        this.table.setVisible(true);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        final String stackTrace = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e);
        this.textAreaErr.setValue(stackTrace);
        this.textAreaErr.setVisible(true);
        Notification.show("Do isch was falsch, Nachricht: ", e.getMessage(), Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```

In table event valueChange are just a notification for testing purpose:

```
private void table_valueChange(final Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Notification.show("Kuck a mole: ", this.table.getSelectedItem().getBean().getGroupName()
            , Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);

}
```

```
All help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for your hint.
The event 'table_valueChange' was still not fired.
The error appears in 'AbstractBeanTable.class', by following function:
 `public BeanItem<BEANTYPE> getSelectedItem()
 {
  if(!this.isMultiSelect())
  {
   return this.getBeanContainerDataSource().getItem(this.getValue());
  }
  return null;
 }`

Comment: Problem is `getSelectedItem` throws the exception because it is getting something that is null, which is not accepted by the function. You could put it in a `try...catch` block, and find the problem in your architecture, that is why there is no selected item.

Answer (score 1):

I am happy, because I found a solution with a help of my friend!

It was still my fault (as expected :-) ). I used the wrong container type:
I used:

```
            final BeanItemContainer<TGroup> mySubClasses = new BeanItemContainer<>(TGroup.class);
```

But it was the wrong container!
I should use instead:

```
final XdevBeanItemContainer<TGroup> mySubClasses = new XdevBeanItemContainer<>(TGroup.class);
```

After I changed it, everything worked fine.
I also searched in the documentation for a hint how I could prevent this for future, but without success.